# Creating Customer Self Service Using NLP APIS?

Tags: architecture, full-text-search, nlp

i want to create a customer self service Using NLP (Natural Language Processing). 
simply the user will enter search sentence like "How do I pay the weekly fee?" and the Self Service will answer the user with the most relevant FAQs  and their answers .

1. i will use [Alchemyapi](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage) (NLP APIs) to analyze the user search sentence.
2. search in the DB (Tagged Answers will be saved there) using the keywords & Entities returned by the NLP APIs.
3. show results to user.
4. update the answers tags according to the user feedback (ranks ) .

this is the logic i will go through to build a simple self service can any one suggest efficient way to do that or an exist APIs do that for me .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you want to build looks like an information retrieval (search engine) problem to me. Assuming you have a set of questions and their answers in your database. What you want to do, is when someone types a question, you find the closes match to his question among the questions in your database, then return the corresponding answer to that.

Implementation-wise. You actually should have two databases. One simple table with question id, question text, and answer text. The other one is your search index, where you build is using the question text and its id as well. I'd suggest you use a [Vector Space Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model). You can use Apache Lucene, Solr, or ElasticSearch for that. I prefer ElasticSearch myself.

P.S. Since you are the one coming up with questions to store in your database, and the only use for these questions is to be matched with users questions, i.e. no one actually sees them. Maybe, then, you can make them more verbose, stuff in more relevant keywords, and play their format to make the matching easier.

P.S. Normally you use TF-IDF for your index, and cosine distance is used for matching text relevance, but I remember once in a similar task, due to the fact that questions are short enough, disabling TF-IDF gave me better results. What I want to say here, is that, you should try to play with these parameters and see what is best for you.

P.S.Other models, as opposed to Vector Space Model, are Binary Independence Model and [Language Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). Check them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). I implemented the Language Model in [this Python library](https://github.com/gr33ndata/irlib), but of course, you can find better libraries for that. I like the Language Model because it requires less memory and has better ways to deal with unseen terms (words).